# how to set allowed values through Rally WSAPI?

Tags: rally

How can one set the allowed values for a Rally attribute (e.g. "Package") using Rally's web services API (2.0)?

I know how to retrieve the allowed values, and the WSAPI documentation says one should be able to POST new ones, or PUT to existing ones to rename them.  But in actuality, POSTing new ones returns an error saying that POST isn't supported, and PUTting to existing ones isn't possible because they don't have _refs to PUT to.

Clearly there must be some way to do this — after all, the GUI can do it — but I haven't managed to figure it out.  Anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the package field... 'Twas a simpler time when this field was created.  Unfortunately it is implemented differently than almost all other dropdowns in Rally and as such is not able to be updated via WSAPI as you have found.  Other field allowed values (including custom fields) have _refs and operate as you expect above.